# How to select from List<IEnumerable<ItemClass>> to IEnumerable<ItemClass>?

Tags: c#, linq

How to select from `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ItemClass>>` to `IEnumerable<ItemClass>`?

here is my code

```
List<IEnumerable<ItemClass>> itemsList = _source.Select(x => x.Items).ToList();
```

as the result I need just all `ItemClass` have as `List<ItemClass>`

Comment: It's not especially easy to understand your question, but what is the type of the .Items property? Is it a type that implements IEnumerable<ItemClass>?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

```
var q = _source.SelectMany(x => x.Items).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

```
IEnumerable<ItemClass> foo = itemsList.SelectMany(i => i);
```